# Strange Behavior on 'extends' keyword over unions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Questions:

1. Why types `M0` and `M1` below are not the same ?
2. Why type `M0` is not exactly equal to type `A` ?
3. What specifically is causing the lack of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) of type `Ext`?

Please explain in terms of the below example:

```js
// Given
type A = '(T extends U) and (U extends T)' 
type B = '(T extends U) and (U NOT extends T)' 
type C = '(T NOT extends U) and (U extends T)' 
type D = '(T NOT extends U) and (U NOT extends T)'
type Ext<T,U,X,Y> = T extends U ? X : Y

//1
type ExtendsCheck<T,U> = T extends U ? (U extends T ?  A : B) : (U extends T ? C : D)
//2
type ExtendsCheck_<T,U> = Ext<T,U,Ext<U,T,A, B>,Ext<U,T,C,D>>


// Why
type T = 'foo' | 'bar'
type U = T
type M0 = ExtendsCheck<T,U> // M0: "(T extends U) and (U extends T)" | "(T extends U) and (U NOT extends T)"
type M1 = ExtendsCheck_<T,U> // M1: "(T extends U) and (U extends T)"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEEsDcFMDsBQAXAngB1qAgqAvKAOQAUAKqLAB7IIAmAzqAKoCUoAhvLaMUxdXUakWhUCgxYAQviJl+NLo1YcuPPgDkA8uSoKGoYaPGZQAYRklyWnQMXM2nbr3mCDIsWhMARC3Osu7ZUc1UH9dV0NjLABRagAeUgAaJkSADUSATQA+GRs9JVAAflBU0AAuUAzERBAARijQWPzTAAtYAGMAawTknII81z5i53C7cmKcctBJNgqR231xsymvFhrgACYGpsFWjs6AfR6mPsb4pJSmuJSk7ETprMSrm8TTRK8srOr10AB1FtQDXIBEIADMAPbg0QAHyIACN2AAnQgNPj9BoAWQADDIdoo9l1jjkQKBsRUAERyUb6IKqeb5Nzk0CwykDQIOOkabQBRYscmY2q4hb0AmHImgEkY2oUqnC+wqJx8alCPmIIA)

**Note:** If this has to do with *Conditional types distributivity* mechanism, please show exactly how this is applied in the above context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly intuit this has to do with the distributivity of conditional types.

TL;DR: It all boils down to when distribution is applied. In the first case `ExtendsCheck` first distributes over `T`, then over `U`. In the second case `Ext<U,T,A, B>` and `Ext<U,T,C,D>` are first resolved, so distribution over `U` happens first, then the outer `Ext` is resolved, and distribution over `T` happens.

Let's consider the order of evaluation for the two types:

```
ExtendsCheck<T = 'foo' | 'bar',U ='foo' | 'bar'> = 
=> T extends U ?  (U extends T ?  A : B) : (U extends T ? C : D)
// Distribute over T (since T extends U is a condition over a naked type parameter)
=> ('foo' extends U ?  (U extends 'foo' ?  A : B) : (U extends 'foo' ? C : D)) |
   ('bar' extends U ?  (U extends 'bar' ?  A : B) : (U extends 'bar' ? C : D))
// Resolve the first conditional in each distribution result, both are true
=> (U extends 'foo' ?  A : B) |
   (U extends 'bar' ?  A : B)
// Distribute over U (since U extends T is a condition over a naked type parameter)
=> ('foo' extends 'foo' ? A : B) | ('bar' extends 'foo' ? A : B) |
   ('foo' extends 'bar' ? A : B) | ('bar' extends 'bar' ? A : B)
// Resolve the conditional types
=> A | B | A | B 
// Union reduction 
=> A | B 
=> '(T extends U) and (U extends T)' | '(T extends U) and (U NOT extends T)'
```

For the second type, things go a bit different

```
type ExtendsCheck_<T= 'foo' | 'bar',U ='foo' | 'bar'> 
=> Ext<T,U, Ext<U,T,A, B>, Ext<U,T,C,D>>
// Resolve Ext<U,T,A, B> for U = T = 'foo' | 'bar'
   Ext<U = 'foo' | 'bar', T = 'foo' | 'bar'> 
   => U extends T ? A : B 
   // Distribute over U 
   => ('foo' extends 'foo' | 'bar' ? A : B) | ('bar' extends 'foo' | 'bar' ? A : B)
   // Both are true
   => A | A 
   // Union reduction 
   => A
// Resolve Ext<U,T,C,D> for U = T = 'foo' | 'bar'
   Ext<U = 'foo' | 'bar', T = 'foo' | 'bar'> 
   => U extends T ? C : D
   // Distribute over U 
   => ('foo' extends 'foo' | 'bar' ? C : D) | ('bar' extends 'foo' | 'bar' ? C : D)
   // Both are true
   => C | C
   // Union reduction 
   => C
// So we get Ext<T, U, A, C> for U = T = 'foo' | 'bar'
=> Ext<T = 'foo' | 'bar', U = 'foo' | 'bar', A, C> 
=> T extends U ? A : C
// Distribute over T
=> ('foo' extends 'foo' | 'bar' ? A : C) | ( 'bar' extends 'foo' | 'bar'? A : C)
// Resolve the conditionals, they are both true
=> A | A
// Union reduction
=> A
=> '(T extends U) and (U extends T)'
```

And yes, distribution in conditional types does break referential transparency, because it can change the order of operations as we see above. To resolve a type alias, all type parameters must be resolved. To resolve a conditional type, distribution must first happen. So it matters if you put a type alias over a conditional type.